Difficulties transforming binary mask from camera frame to world frame
I have 2 RGB cameras in Gazebo11 looking at the same scene from different locations. I threshold the floor space and create a binary mask with white being the ground (free space) and black being obstacles.
My goal is to create an occupancy grid map, but I am having trouble transforming the binary mask from the camera frame to the world frame.
I've created homography matrices for each camera that map to the same world frame, and these work fine, as I use them to localize the robot in the world from the camera view.
I have tried using cv2.warpPerspective like so:
world_mask = cv2.warpPerspective(binary_mask, self.homography_matrix,
                                    (binary_mask.shape[1], binary_mask.shape[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

But the output is very strange, as you may see in the attached image, which contains the binary mask above with the corresponding world transform below for each camera.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I don't think that warpPerspective is the correct operation.
You say your homography matrix1 maps from camera-coordinates to world-coordinates, so why don't you matrix multiply the coordinate of each white pixel of image1 to get a list of world-coordinates on the floor? Repeat for matrix2/image2.
